# How to run proactive dialogs with BotFramework Composer

Tags: botframework

Is it possible to proactively start a dialog from an external endpoint on the BotFramework Composer? It works fine with the SDK but I can't figure out how to do it with the Composer.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible at this time.

Please keep an eye on [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/3566) to see any progress on that. Looks like it is aiming for the next release.